# Cannot navigate to another Activity with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to navigate to another activity (login) using Navigation Component.

Currently `Activity_1` has `navGraph1` and `Activity_2` has `navGraph2`.

I've put a destination in `navGraph1` for `Activity_2`. When I navigate, I get a blank screen, despite `Activity_2` having a nav graph with a starting destination for another fragment.

`onCreate` is not being called, or is at least not being hit by my breakpoint in `Activity_2`.

When I nest `navGraph2` in `navGraph1`, I can navigate to the starting destination fragment in `navGraph2`. This starting destination in `navGraph2` is in `compose`. `Activity_1` seems to bypass `Activity_2` and hosts the fragment directly. However, I'd like `Activity_2` to host it since navigating to `Activity_2` can display more like a pop up modal, hiding things like the bottom nav bar.

I'm not sure what's going on here.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment1">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/Activity2"
        android:name="com.example.Activity2"
        android:label="Activity2" />

</navigation>

// in Activity 1
navController.navigate(R.id.activity2)
```

Activity 2

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_2"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.StartFragment2"
        android:label="StartFragment2" />

</navigation>

class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2)
    }
}

// Layout activity 2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the `navGraph1` and the `navGraph2` files

Comment: I'm not allowed to post the files, but I've edited the post with the code cut down.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Activity 2 was overriding the wrong `onCreate()`. It should be the `onCreate()` with only the `savedInstanceState` parameter.

Comment: It is always the tiniest silliest thing right? I lost a couple of hours on this and your solution worked for me as well.